# What prevents a fake ssl certificate chain

Tags: ssl

If I buy a cert for mycompany.com and I get a valid cert signed by Verisign, What prevents me from generating a fake certificate that is for othercompany.com signed by mycompany?

Doing a man in the middle attack what prevents me from issuing a fake cert for othercompany.com signed by mycompany and include my valid cert as an intermediate CA cert.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security.

Comment: Certificates have to be specifically marked as "Signer Certs" - usually Verisign would not issue you a signer cert.

Comment: Duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20513/using-a-verified-certificate-to-sign-others and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33649/man-in-the-middle-scenario-for-tls

Answer (score 1):

One of the "Basic Constraints" that can be attached to a certificate by the issuer is whether or not the certificate is permitted to sign other certificates. These constraints can't be modified without invalidating the certificate. Since a CA will always issue you with a certificate that is marked as an "End Entity" you won't be able to use it to issue other certificates.

Whilst you could likely still create a certificate issued by an "End Entity", any software that correctly validates a certificate chain will mark such a certificate as invalid and reject it.

Comment: In addition to `Basic Constraints=CA:TRUE,critical`, key usage would need `keyCertSign` and possibly `cRLSign`.